Counting proper $n$-colourings of $C_5$?
Let $C_5$ be the cycle graph on $5$ vertices. How many proper $n$-colourings does $C_5$ have?
My attempt: Let the vertices be $V_1, \ldots, V_5$:

We have $n$ choices for $V_1$.
We have $(n-1)$ choices for $V_2, V_3, V_4$
We have $(n-2)$ choices for $V_5$

Thus, the number of $n$-colourings is $n(n-1)^3(n-2)$. Finally, the colours can be rotated by $5$.
Is this correct?

Try to list all proper 3-colourings. Also look at the related concepts of Necklaces and Lyndon words.

Your question is a special case of this earlier question: prove that the chromatic polynomial of the cycle graph equals $(k-1)^n+(-1)^n(k-1)$

That's almost right, but not quite. You might have $(n-1)$ choices for $V_5$ in some cases since $V_1$ and $V_4$ may have the same colour. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the rotated by $5$ part, but any rotations are already taken into account.
One way to fix your count is to do an inclusion-exclusion argument: let's say you have $(n-1)$-choices for $V_5$ in the end. This isn't exactly right since $V_1$ and $V_5$ may have the same color. However, you can exclude this overcount by thinking of $V_1$ and $V_5$ together as one vertex and counting the number of proper colorings of $C_4$. Can you finish the argument using recursion?
